# Check a regex against return from bacticks into array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I am putting the results of a unix command into an array like this

```
@nums_pre = `cmd | cmd | cmd`;
```

The array @nums_pre now looks something like this

```
$VAR = [
         '1234/some_cmd',
         '4321/some_cmd',
         '1122/some_cmd',
         '3344/some_cmd',
        ];
```

I only want the numbers, so I did this

```
my @nums_post;
foreach my $val (@nums_pre) {
    if ($val =~ /(\d+)/) {
        push @ports_post, $1;
    }
}
```

now the new array @nums_post has only numbers like I want.

Is there a way to do this in one step, with one array? So the results from the `bactick`ed command is checked against a regex as it is being put into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @nums_post = map { /(\d+)/ } `cmd | cmd | cmd`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already executing pipes of cmds on shell, you could add one more `grep` in that pipe

```
my @nums_post = `cmd | cmd | cmd | grep -o '[0-9]+'`
```